# Make error `Undefined reference to aqsat_`

Tags: fortran, libraries, gfortran, linker-errors

I am a beginner Fortran programmer. I am having trouble linking a static library to a Fortran program. In the module `rce_world.f90`, I call a function that is defined in the library `libcamclouds.a`. I get an error suggesting the function is undefined.

I don't think I am linking the library correctly in my Makefile, AND/OR there is some external call in the actual Fortran module that I am missing (we don't need to supply a "use " in the module?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Makefile is:

```
#Defining Variables
objects = homme_lat_lon.o cam_grid.o cam_variables.o rce_world.o initial.o
FC = gfortran
LIBDIR = -L/glade/p/work/aherring/RCE_world_initial/no_SICTHK/moistplume/cam5wv/cfcode_for_adam/
LIBNAM = -lcamclouds
#Makefile
out_data: $(objects)
        $(FC) -g -o out_data $(objects) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAM) -I/sw/include
homme_lat_lon.mod: homme_lat_lon.o homme_lat_lon.f90
        $(FC) -g -c homme_lat_lon.f90 
homme_lat_lon.o: homme_lat_lon.f90
        $(FC) -g -c homme_lat_lon.f90
cam_grid.mod: cam_grid.o cam_grid.f90
        $(FC) -g -c cam_grid.f90
cam_grid.o: cam_grid.f90
        $(FC) -g -c cam_grid.f90
cam_variables.mod: cam_variables.o cam_variables.f90
        $(FC) -g -c cam_variables.f90
cam_variables.o: cam_variables.f90
        $(FC) -g -c cam_variables.f90
rce_world.mod: cam_grid.mod cam_variables.mod rce_world.o rce_world.f90
        $(FC) -g -c rce_world.f90
rce_world.o: cam_grid.mod cam_variables.mod rce_world.f90
        $(FC) -g -c rce_world.f90 
initial.o: homme_lat_lon.mod cam_grid.mod cam_variables.mod rce_world.mod initial.f90
        $(FC) -g -c initial.f90
```

Error log:

```
      rce_world.o: In function __rce_world_MOD_rce_initial': /glade/p/work/aherring/RCE_world_initial/no_SICTHK/moistplum‌​e/cam5wv/cfcode_for_‌​
      adam/rce_world/rce_w‌​orld.f90:168: undefined reference to aqsat_' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [out_data] Error £
```

Comment: Is there a `.mod` file for the Fortran library? If so, you should add the flag `-J /path/to/mod/directory` pointing to the directory that contains the `.mod` files. To have more information, you should copy paste the error log.

Comment: Welcome. It is best to supply more information, you never know where the key is. Some code, full output, error messages. Also, we don't put any greetings in the questions here. I left the "Any help would be greatly appreciated. " in your question, but it is just a noise too. But doesn't need to be removed.

Comment: Also, very important. Your titles should describe your actual problem, not the topic. Tags define the topic. Don't just repeat tags. I put more tags under your question and the current title just repeats them, but doesn't say what is your problem at all. I would try to create a better title for you, but it is better to see the actual error message.

Comment: Pierre - that makes sense to add the -J/path/to/mod/. I've done that, but still have the same problem. Error log: rce_world.o: In function `__rce_world_MOD_rce_initial':
/glade/p/work/aherring/RCE_world_initial/no_SICTHK/moistplume/cam5wv/cfcode_for_adam/rce_world/rce_world.f90:168: undefined reference to `aqsat_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out_data] Error 1

Comment: Perhaps I need to specify the mods files as well?

Comment: Do not put this information into comments. Edit your question. Have you read my previous comments? Please do. We need to see **the code** Where do you call `AQSAT`? Where is it defined? Show *at least* the code of `RCE_INITIAL` and we need to see where `AQSAT` is defined. I am not asking that because of some stupid rules, but the key to the problem is there.

Comment: Please take into account the comments by Vladimir to enhance the reusable character of your question and to obtain better feedback. `undefined reference` hints at a missing object file or library. Maybe we should seek to cover the basics first: is your code using `implicit none`?